# Where should I post questions about algorithms: Stack Overflow or Software Engineering?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm taking Algorithms this term and I wanted to know where I should post questions about material in the course.

Is it [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? Or other SE site? (I wasn't able to discern from the FAQ.)

Comment: Rule of thumb: If there's code in your question, SO. If there's no code, programmers.

Comment: There's also [cs.se], which you might want to investigate

Comment: related: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Questions about designing algorithms, their correctness, or their complexity fit **[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)** best. This is likely to be the best fit for questions that you may have that arise in an algorithms course that is part of a computer science educational program.

If you implement algorithms as part of the course, then questions about the coding part should be asked on **[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**, e.g. “why doesn't my code work?” (post [your whole code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the desired behavior), what library functions to use, etc.

If your implementation is *working* and you want to make it better, take it to **[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Questions about algorithms in the context of analyzing and designing software systems are a good fit on **[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Questions about numerical algorithms in the context of applications to other sciences (statistics, physics, biology, etc.) may be a better fit for **[Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Research-level questions may also be suitable on [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ah, so on SO I would ask why my results aren't correct, or why my code is resulting in an error. And on Programmers, I would ask about say, the mathematical proof behind the algorithm. Is this correct?

Comment: @user39902 Sounds good to me :)

Comment: Even though [programmers.SE] have that in their FAQ, [cs.SE] is the better address for algorithms questions, at least if you want *some* amount of rigor. That's in my completely biased experience.

Comment: No, mathematical proofs go on mathematics.SE!!!

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, great edit.

Comment: @Jeff Please add with your answer what/When to ask Computer Science?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I don't really hang out much on Computer Science, so I've changed my answer to Community Wiki - feel free to edit it with additional relevant content :)

Comment: This answer is no longer correct for SoftwareEngineering.SE. They no longer list algorithms in their [on-topic guide](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The site has been slowly migrating away from that kind of questions for years now.

Comment: @AndresF. this is community wiki, so you're welcome to edit it yourself. I'm not really up-to-date on the various SE programming sites tbh.

Comment: I don't agree with this - Stack Overflow's [on-topic guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states that questions about algorithms are *explicitly* on-topic. There's no explicit requirement that questions about algorithms must include code.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Questions about algorithms are on-topic on Stack Overflow, when the question is about implementing a given algorithm in code. They are off-topic when the question is about designing algorithms, because that has nothing to do with programming - even if the goal is to program the algorithm.

Comment: By my experience: SO is useless. Yes, you can ask questions, but as soon as it involves a bit of maths or problems you don't find on the internet, you either get no answers, answers giving you useless, general advise or just stupid answers. The latter becomes apparent immediate, if one starts talking about maths without having a clue. Even, if the questons is just about debugging a problem involving simple/stupid coding errors, people tend to not be helpful.