# Where should I ask a question about an algorithm (no code)

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

There is a combinatorics problem I want to tackle by writing a program for it. I want feedback on the algorithm I have thought of implementing. I have not implemented it yet because I want to first discuss all the possibilities (and it is obvious that a naive implementation would be useless).

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521/333904), Code Review is supposed to be used to discuss the implementation of the algorithm. The problem is that I do not have any code to review, and I precisely want to avoid writing it until I've had the discussion.

I am assuming either Programmers or Computer Science, but it'd be good to know before asking.